# Esconder conteudo e mudar tamanho de outro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grid

O que eu pretendo e o seguinte é que ao esconder a div de id="content1" a outra div aumente para col-lg-12 o que tenho é o seguinte código:

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6" id="content"> 
               <button id="hide"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> 
               tabela 
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6" id="content1">
                <button id="hide1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>  
                 panel 
         </div> 
</div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#hide").click(function(){
                $("#content").hide();
            });
            $("#show").click(function(){
                $("#content").show();
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#hide1").click(function(){
                $("#content1").hide();
            });
            $("#show1").click(function(){
                $("#content1").show();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Já tentou remover a classe `col-lg-6` e adicionar a `col-lg-12` com as funções `removeClass` e `addClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer as trocas de classes que pretende pode utilizar a função `removeClass` para remover a classe antiga e a função `addClass` para adicionar a nova.

Algo como:

```js
$("#hide").click(function() {
  $("#content").hide(); 
  $("#content1").removeClass("col-lg-6").addClass("col-lg-12");
});

$("#hide1").click(function() {
  $("#content1").hide();
  $("#content").removeClass("col-lg-6").addClass("col-lg-12");
});
```

```css
.col-lg-6 {
  background-color: green;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="content">
    <button id="hide"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> tabela
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="content1">
    <button id="hide1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> panel
  </div>
</div>
```

### Tirando proveito da hierarquia no html

**De acordo com o html indicado** (se for diferente poderá não ser a melhor opção) pode simplificar os clicks utilizando `parent` e `siblings` com:

```
$("#hide, #hide1").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide().siblings().removeClass("col-lg-6").addClass("col-lg-12");
});
```

O `parent` navega do botão `hide` até ao `<div>` que é o que quer esconder, dai o `hide`. Depois com `siblings` apanha o `<div>` ao lado e faz a troca de classes.

Repare também que agrupei as duas funções de `click` numa só uma vez que a navegação é feita através da hierarquia de elementos e por isso não depende especificamente de um id ou classe.

Exemplo a funcionar:

```js
$("#hide, #hide1").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide().siblings().removeClass("col-lg-6").addClass("col-lg-12");
});
```

```css
.col-lg-6 {
  background-color: green;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="content">
    <button id="hide"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> tabela
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="content1">
    <button id="hide1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> panel
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentação:

- [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)